# Making py2exe produce `.py` files

Tags: python, py2exe

Is there any way to make py2exe output `.py` source files instead of byte-compiled `.pyc` files in the library?

Comment: You already have the .py files -- they're input to py2exe.  Since you already have .py files, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Instead of having py2exe output `.pyc` in the library, I want it to output `.py` files. This is so it will be easier for me to debug.

Comment: -1: You already have .py files.  This makes no sense.  The comment doesn't help.  Try updating the question with some rational explanation for why you want .py files *when you already have the .py files*.

Comment: py2exe copies a lot of libraries from `site-packages`, sometimes changing their structure. I wouldn't want to be moving all those `.py` files manually. I still want to enjoy py2exe's package discovery/organization capabilities, but I want it to just copy the `.py` files instead of making `.pyc` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it long ago, so I hope I remember correctly:

- Set compressed to False, so py2exe won't create a Zip'd library file.
- Set optimize to zero, so py2exe will write `pyc` files.

**UPDATE**: Ram Rachum is right, use the `skip_archive` option instead of `compressed`.

You won't be able to modify your main Python file, since it will be embedded into the main executable, so keep that to a minimum. Then you'll be able to replace the `pyc` files with your `py` files manually in your distribution as needed. No reason to replace the standard libraries, however, only your own code.

(It is not optimal for debugging, but I guess you want to fix some problem happening only to the release build of your software this way.)

Please let me know if it does not work and I'll try to help.

**UPDATE**:

I've just read the relevant parts of the py2exe source code. It seems that py2exe does not support it out of the box. So we've left with the option to touch its source code.

You can easily modify `py2exe` to support this mode. See the `byte_compile` function in `build_exe.py`. There's a call to the `compile` built-in function in it, which you can replace with a `copy_file`. Don't forget to modify the destination file name (`dfile`) to have the extension `.py` instead of `.pyc` or `.pyo`. I know that it is patchwork, but I don't see any other possibility to solve your problem.

You can also add a new `py2exe` option or introduce a new `optimize` value for this if you're curious. It would be an open-source contribution to py2exe, actually. ;)

Comment: I'm already able to manually replace them with py files. (Also, I'm doing `skip_archive` to have a folder instead of a zip file.)

I just wish py2exe won't try to be that smart; I wish it'll just copy the original package contents for each package into the library. Asides from it compiling the `.py` files, it also misses some data files for some scientific packages for example.

Comment: You can list the data files missed by `py2exe` explicitly in the `data_files` option. See also: http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files